# Автоотключение USB при копировании

Tags: windows, usb, ос

Всем привет. Пару дней назад столкнулся с проблемой копирования видеофайлов с внешнего носителя  (HDD 1Tb) на ноут ASUS N53j - через USB-карман.

**Суть проблемы:**

Подключаю винт(карман) - начинает копироваться файл потом резко отпадает мой карман из списка устройств (копирование обрывается) и начинается авто-переподключение устройства к ноуту. Однажды удалось скопировать файл размером 800Мб (это самый маленький оказался).

При подключении к другому ПК или ноуту работает нормально без отключений и проблем.

Есть вероятность что стоит какая-то блокировка USB. Реестр смотрел вроди как все чисто в ветке (инфу нашел вот [здесь](http://dontreg.ru/kak-zapretit-zapis-dannykh-na-fleshku-sredstvami-windows))

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\StorageDevicePolicies
```

в процессах и в PATH тоже, вроди как, ничего лишнего.
Драйвера тоже на месте, но детально разбираться с дровами у меня времени пока что - не было (я просто скопировал инфу на другой комп)

Кто знает в чем может быть проблема?

Заранее благодарен за ответ!

Comment: Повтори ту же операцию через livecd linux, а потом расскажи как оно.

Comment: Да точно - это вариант. Но этот ноут я, возможно, увижу через пару недель. Если увижу то обязательно попробую! 
Спасибо.
PS/ Кстати, как по мне то в принципе не обязательно использовать Linux.

Comment: Нет обязательно, потому что там нет реестра, виндовых дров, виндового ядра и прочего от майков. Этим методом можно понять, что проблема в железе или оси.

Comment: @don Rumata Сегодня был рядом ноутом попробовал. В общем ***Вы ПРАВЫ*** под линем все скопировалось 35Гб без отвалов и с очень хорошей  скоростью. В начале попробовал через Тотал но скопировались только картинки 2Мб, а когда видео-файл 800Мб - отпало моментально.

получается проблема как обычно в Винде ... 

Что можете посоветовать: стоит искать проблему в ОСи или сразу на снос, хотя можно попробовать все дрова переставить для начала (была-ни-была)

В любом случае **СПАСИБО**!

Comment: Если есть возможность (позволяет время и размер носителя) - я ставлю людям 2 ОС с загрузкой по дефолту в винду и таймаутом в 3 секунды. Народ не замечает что у них на компе 4 ОС (докидываю ещё CloneZilla и Grml LiveCD), но зато когда звонит и говорит, что "как-то оно стало работать не так" - я говорю что нажать и когда, чтобы прогрузиться в бубен. А там тоже есть тимвьювер и сеть. Если комп юзается чисто как печатная машинка, медиаплеер и интернет-киоск - вообще винду не ставлю. Ставлю только для специфичных задач типа графики и САПР.

Comment: @donRumata ок. спасибо. если мне дадут этот ноут то буду думать уже. А пока что там есть админ, ото пусть и думает, я причину этой траблы искал ради собственного интереса (и что бы в будущем помнить) т.к. не смог скопировать видео,..